# Typescript type assertion for private Instance class variables

Tags: typescript, assert

How is it possible to assert that a private class instance variable exists in typescript ?

```js
export class A {
  private myArray?: string[];

  private constructor() {}

  private assertMyArray(): asserts this is this & {
    myArray: string
  } {
    if (!this.myArray) throw new Error('myArray is not defined');
  }

  private doSomething() {
    this.assertMyArray();
    const len = this.myArray.length; // <--- ts error here (this is never somehow)
  }
}
```

After calling type assertion ts will error with

```
TS2339: Property 'myArray' does not exist on type 'never'.   
The intersection 'this & { myArray: string; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'myArray' exists in multiple constituents and is private in some.
```

Changing from `private` to `public` signature works as expected

Comment: `protected` will work to.

Comment: I see you have open a bug on GitHub : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49709

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler yes, but not sure if it's a real bug or it is by design

Comment: Private properties are difficult to refer to.  You could refactor to use generics, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnKMvm) maybe, but I don't know if that's worth it to you.  Let me know if you want me to write this up as an answer, or if I'm not addressing something about the question.

Comment: @jcalz, yeah that does partially solves the issue, though as you said it is not worth it to refactor as there could be multiple private instance variables and it would not make any sense to extend with that many generics only for type assertion, I guess I can further stick with an `assertion` like function call (that will throw the error if property is not defined) and after that just use the `!` assertion operator :)
Thanks though